# Density based clustering that allows user to specify number of clusters

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I have data that consists of roughly 100,000 points on a 2-d graph. Each point has X and Y coordinates. I'm looking for an algorithm that will cluster these points based on density but I want to specify the number of clusters.

I originally tried K-Means since this would allow me to specify the number of clusters. However, my data naturally "clumps" into ridges. K-Means would inevitably bisect some of these ridges. DBSCAN seems like a better fit simply due to the shape of my data, but with DBSCAN I can't specify the number of clusters I'd like.

Essentially what I'm trying to find is an algorithm that will optimally cluster the graph into N groups based on density. Where N is supplied by me. At this point I don't care where it's implemented (R, Python, FORTRAN...).

Any direction you can provide would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered hierarchical clustering (with Ward linkage)? In my hands it worked rather well to separate based on distance. And you specify `k` in `cutree`.

Comment: Thanks, @Alexlok! I'll give that a try

Comment: @Alexlok this ended up working perfectly for me. If you'd like to repost your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an area of high density, the points tend to be close together, so clustering on the (euclidian) distance may give similar results (not always).

For example, with these three normals in 2 dimensions:

```
x1 <- mnormt::rmnorm(200, c(10,10), matrix(c(20,0,0,.1), 2, 2))
x2 <- mnormt::rmnorm(100, c(10,20), matrix(c(20,0,0,.1), 2, 2))
x3 <- mnormt::rmnorm(300, c(23, 15), matrix(c(.1,0,0,35), 2, 2))

xx <- rbind(x1, x2, x3)

plot(xx, col=rep(c("grey10","pink2", "green4"), times=c(200,100,300)))
```

[image: three clusters in 2 dimensions]

We can apply different clustering algorithms:

```
# hierarchical
clustering <- hclust(dist(xx,
                          method = "euclidian"),
                     method = "ward.D")
h.cl <- cutree(clustering, k=3)

# K-means and dbscan
k.cl <- kmeans(xx, centers = 3L)
d.cl <- dbscan::dbscan(xx, eps = 1)
```

And we see on this particular example, the hierarchical clustering and DBSCAN produced similar results, whereas K-means cut one of the clusters in a wrong way.

```
opar <- par(mfrow=c(3,1), mar = c(1,1,1,1))

plot(xx, col = k.cl$cluster, main="K-means")
plot(xx, col = d.cl$cluster, main="DBSCAN")
plot(xx, col = h.cl, main="Hierarchical")

par(opar)
```

[image: the same data clustered with 3 algorithms]

Of course, there is no guarantee this will work on your particular data.